# No me funciona la redirección de Mercado Pago al finalizar el pago PHP

Tags: php, mercadopago

Espero que me puedan ayudar con este problema de Mercado Pago.

Tengo este código:

```
<?php 
// SDK de Mercado Pago
require __DIR__ .  '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Agrega credenciales
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('xxxxxxxxxx');

// Crea un objeto de preferencia
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

// Crea un ítem en la preferencia
$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->title = 'Mi producto';
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->unit_price = 75.56;
$preference->items = array($item);

$preference->back_urls = array(
    "success" => "https://www.tu-sitio/success",
    "failure" => "http://www.tu-sitio/failure",
    "pending" => "http://www.tu-sitio/pending"
);
$preference->auto_return = "approved";


$preference->save();

 ?>
<a href="<?php echo $preference->sandbox_init_point; ?>" class="btn btn-pill btn-danger">Pagar</a>
```

Cuando voy a la mi página me tira error 500, pero si le saco esta parte funciona perfecto, pero no me redirecciona a ninguna parte

```
$preference->back_urls = array(
    "success" => "https://www.tu-sitio/success",
    "failure" => "http://www.tu-sitio/failure",
    "pending" => "http://www.tu-sitio/pending"
);
$preference->auto_return = "approved";
```

Por favor, si alguien me puede ayudar, que Mercado Pago no me da respuesta.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué dice el mensaje de error?

Comment: Hola! Nada, solo error 500

Comment: ¿Estás usando el modo modal de Mercado Pago? La doc dice que en ese caso las redirecciones deben hacerse de otra forma. Dice esto: [*Ten en cuenta que las backs_urls **solo funcionan para modo redirect y mobile**. No al usar modo modal, ya que para volver al sitio toma la URL del form action.*](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/advanced-integration/#bookmark_url_de_retorno)

Comment: Estoy usando el  modo redirect, porque el modal no funciona. Habia visto ese enunciado, y puse todo lo que me dice Mercado Pago, me canse de buscar diferente forma.

Comment: YA lo resolvi! Era el $_GET que puse en la url de redirección! GRacuas A. Cedano por tus repuestas!